# Asp.net core MVC DatatTypes in model and null values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have simple model MyModel:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string 1stString { get; set; }
public string 2ndString { get; set; }
public string 3rdString { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
```

In my controller I then have:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyView(int? id)
{
    var model = await _db.MyModel.ToListAsync(); ///HERE IT THROWS ERROR
    ViewBag.Id = id ?? 1;
    return View(model);
}
```

I have problem that I have Null values in my Db so it automatically throws [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiTY9.png) because of datetime I suppose?

Comment: Use nullable DateTime and remove [DataType(DataType.Date)] attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the DataType Annotation from the DateTime Property and Make it Nullable

```
[Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string 1stString { get; set; }
    public string 2ndString { get; set; }
    public string 3rdString { get; set; }

    public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
```

If you will like to get only the date you can decorate your ViewModel with this:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exatly what I was searching for.